# C-v does not work as scroll down on wsl emacs

Tags: scroll, emacs, key-bindings, wsl-2

C-v causes "paste"  in wsl ubuntu emacs. How can C-v be remapped to "scroll-down-command"?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to bind `C-v` to `scroll-down-command` in the `global-map` this is the answer:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-v") 'scroll-down-command)
```

If your question is how to remap all keys that are bound to `yank` (Emacs's version of "paste") to `scroll-down-command` instead, then this:

```lisp
(global-set-key [remap yank] 'scroll-down-command)
```

That said, `C-v` in Emacs should be `scroll-up-command` by default, not `scroll-down-command`.

If your question is how to stop some window manager or other application from overriding Emacs key bindings, someone else will have to help.

Comment: `C-v`'s default behavior is named `scroll-up`, but the action it takes is what any modern human would call "scroll down". The emacs name for the behavior predates modern terminology, just like the window/frame confusion. But I agree it seems likely that a window manager or terminal is stealing the key, unless we have somehow gotten into `cuda-mode`. I'd try `C-h k C-v` to confirm that Emacs is getting the key at all.

Comment: *"any modern human"* - presumptuous. It all depends what point of view you take: that of the viewport (window) or that of the buffer text. The window moves down, or the text moves up? Are you scrolling the window or the text? It has **nothing whatsoever to do with "modern"** anything, humans or other.